# Portrait Landscape switching with Flex box and ios

Tags: html, css, ios

I have a responsive website which I use a flex box to display 4 x tabs at 25% width each,

50% width @ 768px:
[image]

and 100% width @ 650px:

[image]

This works fine in all of my tests however, I have just found that on iOS ONLY, at 768px, it doesn't honour the flexbox and wraps box 2 creating a less than appealing layout.

[image]

I'm not sure know how to test and debug on iOS or why this only happens on iOS but hoping someone has been there, done that?

CODE

HTML:

```
<section class="row page_link_tabs" role="main">

    <div class="tab">
        <a href="/our-team/" title="About Us">
            <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/1.-About-Us.png" width="481" height="481" alt="About Us">
            <div class="vertical_gradient"></div>
            <h3>About Us</h3>
        </a>
    </div>

    
    <div class="tab">
        <a href="/our-partners/" title="Partners">
            <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/2.-Partners.png" width="481" height="481" alt="Partners">
            <div class="vertical_gradient"></div>
            <h3>Partners</h3>
        </a>
    </div>

    
    <div class="tab">
        <a href="/case-studies/" title="Case Studies">
            <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/3.-Case-Studies.png" width="481" height="481" alt="Case Studies">
            <div class="vertical_gradient"></div>
            <h3>Case Studies</h3>
        </a>
    </div>

    
    <div class="tab">
        <a href="/loyalty-referral-program/" title="Loyalty Referral program">
            <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/4.-Loyalty-Referral-program.png" width="481" height="481" alt="Loyalty Referral program">
            <div class="vertical_gradient"></div>
            <h3>Loyalty Referral program</h3>
        </a>
    </div>

</section>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    *zoom: 1;
}

.page_link_tabs {
    display: flex;
}

.page_link_tabs .tab {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    width: 25%;
}

.page_link_tabs .tab img {
    width: 100%;
}

.page_link_tabs .tab h3 {
    position:absolute;
    left: 2rem;
    bottom: 2rem;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-size: 2.125rem;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .page_link_tabs {
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .page_link_tabs .tab {
        width: 50%;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    .page_link_tabs .tab {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to get a more helpful response, can you please include the code in your example attempt above?